# Convert dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{'OPPHJFPK_00001': ['K00879', 'PF00370.22'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00002': ['', 'PF01070.19', 'COG1304'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00003': ['', 'COG3279', 'GH65'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00004': ['', 'PF13460.7', 'COG0451'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00005': ['']}
```

And I aim to obtain a dataframe in which each feature (always starting with K, P, C or G) is in the right column:

```
| OPPHJFPK_00001 | K00879 | PF00370.22 |          |      |
| OPPHJFPK_00002 |        | PF01070.19 | COG1304  |      |
| OPPHJFPK_00003 |        |            | COG3279  | GH65 |
| OPPHJFPK_00004 |        | PF13460.7  |          |      |
| OPPHJFPK_00005 |        |            |          | GTA  |
```

I already tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

But I'm getting it unformatted:

```
| OPPHJFPK_00001 | K00879 | PF00370.22 |          |
| OPPHJFPK_00002 |        | PF01070.19 | COG1304  |
| OPPHJFPK_00003 |        | COG3279    | GH65     |
| OPPHJFPK_00004 |        | PF13460.7  |          |     
| OPPHJFPK_00005 |        | GTA        |          |
```

Is there any pandas feature to deal with this?

Notice that the first column is always right because in the dictionary when missing the feature, an empty string is in its place. For the remaining options, when absent, there's nothing in its place in the dictionary.

Any idea on how to solve this? I'd be really thankfull.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
data = {'OPPHJFPK_00001': ['K00879', 'PF00370.22',''], 
'OPPHJFPK_00002': ['', 'PF01070.19', 'COG1304'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00003': ['', 'COG3279', 'GH65'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00004': ['', 'PF13460.7', 'COG0451'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00005': ['','','']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Then for inverting the matrix you can use `DataFrame.transpose()`

Answer (score 1):

Assumed the `d` is your `dict`

```
s=pd.Series(d).explode()
s=s[s!='']
df=pd.crosstab(index=s.index,columns=s.str[0],values=s,aggfunc='first')
df
col_0                 C     G       K           P
row_0                                            
OPPHJFPK_00001      NaN   NaN  K00879  PF00370.22
OPPHJFPK_00002  COG1304   NaN     NaN  PF01070.19
OPPHJFPK_00003  COG3279  GH65     NaN         NaN
OPPHJFPK_00004  COG0451   NaN     NaN   PF13460.7
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to reshape the dict:

```
a = {'OPPHJFPK_00001': ['K00879', 'PF00370.22'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00002': ['', 'PF01070.19', 'COG1304'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00003': ['', 'COG3279', 'GH65'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00004': ['', 'PF13460.7', 'COG0451'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00005': ['']}

# Reshape it so that each value is a duct of {letter: value}
a = {k: {x[0]: x for x in v if x} for k, v in a.items()}
# And then take care of those empty values
a = {k: v if v else {'K': float('nan')} for k, v in a.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the expected output, the dict must have the following format:

```
d = {'OPPHJFPK_00001': ['K00879', 'PF00370.22', '', ''], 
'OPPHJFPK_00002': ['', 'PF01070.19', 'COG1304', ''], 
'OPPHJFPK_00003': ['', '', 'COG3279', 'GH65'], 
'OPPHJFPK_00004': ['', 'PF13460.7', '', ''], 
'OPPHJFPK_00005': ['','','', 'GTA']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

You're obtaining this format because your arrays are not with same length.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, but that option doesn't solve the question. In this case i can't change the dictionary so I have to work with what I have.